# jest.fn() is being called multiple times

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing my react-native app components with jest and enzyme. In order to spy on functions passed as props, I am using `jest.fn()`. When I run the tests, I am getting errors saying `Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called two times`. This error is appearing while testing `onPress` methods.

I tried removing anonymous functions that invoke prop methods in my components;  directly referencing to `onPress` method of `<TouchableOpacity/>` inside the component without invoking it from component's prop; re-rendering test-component before the test-case. But no success.

```
/*BackButton.js*/

import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'expo';
import { iconStyle, Colors } from '../constants';

const styles = {
    icon: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 40
    }
};

function BackButton(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={()=>props.navigate()}
         style={{width: 50}}
        >
            <Icon.Ionicons
             name={`${iconStyle}-refresh`}
             style={styles.icon}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
 }

 export default BackButton;

=======================================
/*BackButton-test.js*/

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import BackButton from '../BackButton';

describe('navigate action', () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<BackButton navigate={spy}/>);

    it('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
       wrapper.prop('navigate')();
    });

    it('calls once', () => {
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
 });
```

Moreover, when I directly called `spy()` inside `beforeEach`, it also got called 2 times.

Comment: Take the `wrapper.prop('navigate')` out form the `beforeEach()` function

Comment: Exactly! I guess I realized the real problem. I thought this code works linearly, but, turns out it is not. `spy` is getting called as many times as `it` blocks are encountered in `describe` block. Thanks for the quick answer @RuChernChong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `wrapper.prop('navigate')` out from the `beforeEach()` function

Your `beforeEach()` is running the number of times of `it()` you have